# How to make multiple circles with Canvas JS

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a function that makes a circle when I click on a button but if I keep clicking the button, it just copies the circle in the same place. I'm trying to figure out a way to make multiple circles with different xy positions. I have the code below

```
function nerdsAssemble(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("boop");
if (canvas.getContext)
  {
    var con=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var W=canvas.width / 2;
    var H=canvas.height / 2;
    var rad=45;
    con.beginPath();
    con.arc(W, H, rad, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    con.stroke();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you can pass different center values and that will create new circles

Comment: The `W` and `H` are the x & y coordindates of the center of the circle. Move those: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you're putting the circle at a pre-determined location:

```
var W=canvas.width / 2;
var H=canvas.height / 2;
```

This is the center of the canvas element. As a side note - the variable names **W** and **H** are a bit misleading because the corresponding  parameters of the **arc()** function are actually the x and y position. Anyway, If you want to have circles at random positions, you can utilize the **Math.random()** function. It returns a random number between 0 and 1. If you multiply that by the width / height of the canvas you'll have circles all around the canvas.

```js
function nerdsAssemble() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("boop");
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var con = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var W = Math.random() * canvas.width;
    var H = Math.random() * canvas.height;
    var rad = 45;
    con.beginPath();
    con.arc(W, H, rad, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    con.stroke();
  }

}
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", nerdsAssemble);
```

```html
<canvas id="boop" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
<button id="myButton">
Circle
</button>
```

### Followup

If you want new circles appear next to each other from left to the right we need to change some things.
First we need some variables that hold the position of a circle. Let's call those xPosition and yPosition. The initial value of xPosition should be 45. Why 45? 45 is the radius of the circle as determined by the equally named variable radius and a horizontal position of 45 means we're touching the left side of the canvas.

Now if we increment the xPosition by radius * 2 (90, is the diameter of the circle) after drawing a circle, the next circle will be next to the last one.

Here's some code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("boop");
var radius = 45;
var xPosition = radius;
var yPosition = canvas.height / 2;
var con = canvas.getContext("2d");

function nerdsAssemble() {
  con.beginPath();
  con.arc(xPosition, yPosition, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  con.stroke();
  xPosition += radius * 2;
}
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", nerdsAssemble);
```

```html
<canvas id="boop" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
<button id="myButton">
Circle
</button>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do the same thing, but instead of having it appear randomly, have it go in line? I've tried working that out, but I think my formatting isn't permitting it to happen.

Comment: ```@obscure``` please, I didn't know how to tag

Comment: You mean horizontally next to each other from left to right? Or randomly in line upwards downwards?

Comment: Horizontally I mean ```@obscure```

Comment: @JaleeyahAnderson - I refined my answer above!

Comment: No problem @JaleeyahAnderson. Glad I could help! =)